Why does Saitama's ability to breathe in space seem inconsistent between different One-Punch Man chapters?
In the One-Punch Man manga, Saitama's ability to breathe in space appears inconsistent across different chapters.
In Volume 7, Chapter 36 (2014), Boros delivers a powerful kick that sends Saitama flying to the moon. Upon landing, Saitama is shown holding his breath, suggesting he can't breathe in the vacuum of space.

Now, fast forward to Chapter 167 (2022), where Saitama battles Awakened Garou on Io, one of Jupiter's moons. Surprisingly, Saitama doesn't hold his breath this time. He even talks and fights freely, suggesting that he can breathe in Io's extremely thin atmosphere—something that would be impossible for humans.


Did something happen between these two chapters that enhanced Saitama's abilities, allowing him to survive in space without holding his breath?  Or is there another explanation for this apparent inconsistency?

Io has an atmosphere, not a pleasant one, but it has one.

@Separatrix I see. Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited my post accordingly.

There was nobody to talk to on the moon.

I the first example it looks like he is holding his breath because he assumes he will have to without knowing.  Perhaps he has just learned it is not needed in the interim.

I don't have the proper images handy to include as citations in a proper answer, but in manga chapter 89 (webcomic 56), Zombieman has a conversation with Dr. Genus about how everyone has a limiter placed on their abilities by God, but Saitama has somehow removed his through pure force of will.  I don't think its explicitly stated in the same chapter, but the implication is made that Saitama's powers will always increase exponentially to match any threat. Saitama, Garou, and a few others have the ability of Accelerated Development (introduced in chapter 11)
